# Javascripted HTML table addition not displaying when printed

Tags: javascript, html, printing, html-table

I've coded a table in HTML. However, there are some variables that could be within the table that need me to append an extra entry at the end if the variable is included.

I have the code HTML which is linked to a JavaScript block of code:

```js
var sku = "".concat("[%ITEM_SKU1%]", "[%ITEM_SKU2%]", "[%ITEM_SKU3%]", "[%ITEM_SKU4%]");
var mini_sku = "-01969-|-01970-|-01971-|-01972-|";
var personRegExp = new RegExp(mini_sku);
if (personRegExp.test(sku)) {
  document.getElementById("Additional").innerHTML = '<td class="is2"> \
            <font color="#FF0000" size="+3"><b>+</b></font>          </td>\
          <td class="is2"><strong> \
            Additional Item          </strong></td>\
          <td class="is2"> \
            Additional Item(s) (Title)           </td>\
          <td class="is6"> \
            <div align="right"> \
              n/a           </div>          </td>\
          <td class="is6"><div align="right"> n/a</div></td>';
}
```

```html
<tr id="Additional"></tr>
```

The code basically searches the variable "sku" for the numbers listed in "mini_sku". If they're there, the extra entry to the table is added.

This code works fine when I open the .html file in a browser. When I try to print the file directly, however, the code doesn't work and the extra entry isn't added. Is there a way to make it work correctly when I go to print the file?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "print"? transform to another format? (like pdf) or just send the file to the printer machine?

Comment: I mean to literally send the file to a printing machine to be printed, sorry for the ambiguous phrasing. @JulioPérez

Comment: ok, no problem. Another question: are you sending the file to the printer using window.print?

Answer (score 0):

I have read your comment. Try to explain a bit more your problem since the question is to wide or a bit vague.

Remember Javascript is a interpreted programming language. Javascripts need to be interpreted by a browser to do work. If you send it to print without opening the file first in the browser the javascript part of your code will never work. That's why when you print you can't see the extra column on your table.

What you can do? Well... I suppose you have this table inside a div tag (let's name it "yourdiv") so... You can put a button on the file you want to print:

```
<div id="tablediv">
    <!-- Here you have your table with the extra column -->
</div>

<input type="button" name="Print" value="Print" onclick="toprint();">
```

The javascript function:

```
function toprint() {

     var content= document.getElementById(tablediv);
      var contentprint = window.open(' ', 'Table');
      contentprint.document.write(content.innerHTML );
      contentprint.document.close();
      contentprint.print( );
      contentprint.close();

}
```

Comment: Did you miss a link here?